# Empty lines on top of drop-down menus (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: gui, menu

When I open some drop down menus, like choosing file type in Open Office or image resolution in Gimp, the first few items are just empty lines, and they only disappear after scrolling down, plus the item names seem to be gray instead of white, even though they still work normally.

Like this:

[image]

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatelly i can't help you with empty lines: UI set first/selected item to your current cursor position by default - it's fine for me, so i didn't seek the way to change it.

But i suffered from the same problem with the dark font color in drop-down list items, which makes item names hard to read. My environment also is Ubuntu 16.04 with "Ambiance" UI theme, so i probably can help to fix that:

First of all, as you probably know, all system themes located there: "/usr/share/themes/", and some "Tweak Tools" (such as: "Unity Tweak Tool" (preferable) or "GNOME Tweak Tool") helps to set different themes for user's environment.

In my case some omission of my "Ambiance" theme was found in "gtk-2.0" settings, saved in "/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc":

```
# Workaround style for menus where the text color is used instead of the fg color.
style "menuitem_text_is_fg_color_workaround" {
    text[NORMAL]        = @fg_color
    text[PRELIGHT]      = @selected_fg_color
    text[SELECTED]      = @selected_fg_color
    text[ACTIVE]        = @fg_color
    text[INSENSITIVE]   = "#99958b"
}
```

more precisely:

```
text[NORMAL]        = @fg_color
```

which makes drop-down list items font color almost the same as the background color, so to fix that all you need is to change "**@fg_color**" in that line to something else, such as "**@selected_fg_color**" (it defined as white), or use static color, for example: **"#9e9e9e"** (light "Mouse Gray" color).

Looks simple, but there is one problem: "Ambiance" - is the system default UI theme, which saved in system default location ("/usr/share/themes/"). So, to change it, you need the root credentials, and you will change default system parameters, which, i believe, isn't the best way to act.

So i recommend to create your own theme, based on "Ambiance", simply by copying folder "/usr/share/themes/Ambiance" into folder ".themes" in your Home Directory ("/home/**[MyUser]**/.themes/"), then rename copied theme folder from "Ambiance", to something else (e.g. "MyAmbiance"), then change it (.../.themes/MyAmbiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc) as described above (with your basic credentials, cause you changing your own theme, not a system one), and finaly set your new created theme as your default one, using some "Tweak Tool", e.g. "Unity Tweak Tool".